# Using Google Maps / Waze API

Tags: google-maps, developer-tools, waze

My team and I are creating a device a GPS device and I need to know which API either #Waze or #GoogleMaps can communicate with my device and how!!

Answer (score 4):

Go check the waze documentation

https://developers.google.com/waze/intro-transport